# Datorama & Google Analytics Data Stream - 403: User Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

Having a problem where Datorama data streams connected to Google Analytics are failing due to  `'403: User Rate Limit Exceeded'` - we have attempted to spread the credential load across different accounts but had no success with that.

Reading this article - [Limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) a fix is to increase the quota from 100 to 1000 requests per 100 seconds in Google Cloud Platform.

Needing some guidance on how to set up the API connection in Google Cloud Platform and the credentials needed to link the change with Google Analytics.

Has anyone else had a similar issue before?

Comment: Datorama support is the best option. Alternative is to create reports and use TotalConnect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of google quotas.  These quotas are split up in project based and user based quotas.  Project based quotas can be extended user based quotas can not.

Project based. (Can be increased)

- 50,000 requests per project per day, which can be increased.
- 50 write requests per project per day, which can be increased

User based: (Can **NOT** be increased)

- 10 queries per second (QPS) per IP address.
- In the API Console, there is a similar quota referred to as Requests per 100 seconds per user. By default, it is set to 100 requests per 100 seconds per user and can be adjusted to a maximum value of 1,000. But the number of requests to the API is restricted to a maximum of 10 requests per second per user.
- If your application makes all API requests from a single IP address (i.e., on behalf of your users), use the userIP or quotaUser parameter with each request to get full QPS quota for each user. See the standard query parameters summary for details.
- 1.5 queries per second (QPS) per Account ID

> '403: User Rate Limit Exceeded'

Is a flood protection quota.   Each user denoted by ip address or the user who is currently authenticated can max make 100 requests per 100 seconds.  This number is not perfect due to clock skew.  Sometimes you can make 110 requests sometimes only 90.  The only thing you can do with this quota error is to slow down and implement exponential backoff.   This is a user based quota and can NOT be extended. Your only option is to slow down.

[Limits & Quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas)